# How to build SRP for Win32 with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, openssl, srp-protocol

I need to build Secure Remote Password protocol library (SRP/libsrp) for old project from 2010. I can't figure out how to build it for Win32.

I found this link with latest source code:

http://srp.stanford.edu/download.html

Version 2.1.2 was used in project. There is link for Win32-binaries, but it's dead.
So the only way to get binaries is to compile the source code.

In Win32\README was said to put OpenSSL includes and compiled libs in related folder (include, lib, etc.). 
I can't figure out what version of OpenSSL should be used. On the web page was said something about patching version 1.0.0.0, but I used the latest version of OpenSSL.

Then it was said to open "srp_openssl.dsw" file (which is VC++ 6 Workspace) and rebuild everything to get binaries.

The result is hundreds of errors related to the obsolete language and related to the OpenSSL. Also need to take into account that OpenSSL changed library names.

So, is the only way - to use OpenSSL 1.0.0.0 and VC++ 6 to build SRP? Also, are there any binaries in the internet?

Comment: You should migrate to openssl 1.0.1+, it has SRP built-in.

Comment: Ah, I'm newbie and I thought it's different libraries, because classes in project and in OpenSSL's SRP were called different. Thank you. )